# OutputCache's VaryByParam doesn't seem to be working

Tags: asp.net, caching

This is a sample demo that I have created to try explaining myself about VaryByParam attribute of OutputCache:

The Markup:

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="10" VaryByParam="ID" %>

<asp:Button ID="SetQueryStringButton1" runat="server" 
                Text="Set query string ID=1 and redirect"
                PostBackUrl="~/OutputCachingUsingQueryString/Default.aspx?ID=1" />
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="SetQueryStringButton2" runat="server" 
                Text="Set query string ID=2 and redirect"
                PostBackUrl="~/OutputCachingUsingQueryString/Default.aspx?ID=2" />
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="SetQueryStringButton3" runat="server" 
                Text="Set different query string and redirect"
                PostBackUrl="~/OutputCachingUsingQueryString/Default.aspx?ABCD=3" />
```

The Code-behind:

```
if (IsPostBack)
    {
        string key = Request.QueryString.GetKey(0);
        MessageLabel.Text = "The value of query string " + key + " is : " + Request.QueryString[key] + "<br/>";
        MessageLabel.Text += DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
    }
```

When I click first two buttons, then according to the definition of VaryByParam, it caches the page for ID = 1 and ID = 2. But when i click the third button, it does cache the page for ABCD = 3.
What i was expecting is the page shouldn't be cached for ABCD=3, because I haven't specified it in VaryByParam. I get the same dateTime when i repeatedly click the third button.

**EDIT START**:
I also tried it this way:

The Markup:

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="10" VaryByParam="ID" %>
<asp:Label ID="MessageLabel" runat="server"/><br/>
<a href="Default.aspx?ID=1">Click Me and pass ID=1</a><br/>
<a href="Default.aspx?ID=2">Click Me and pass ID=2</a><br/>
<a href="Default.aspx?ABCD=3">Click Me and pass ABCD=3</a><br/>
```

The Code-behind:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
   if (Request.QueryString.Keys.Count > 0)
   {
      string key = Request.QueryString.GetKey(0);
      MessageLabel.Text = "The value of query string: " + key + " is: " +  Request.QueryString[key] + "<br/>";
      MessageLabel.Text += DateTime.Now.ToString();
   }
}
```

When I click the third , it displays the MessageLabel after I click it couple of times. Some kind of weird behavior I am experiencing here.

**EDIT END**

Please shed some light on what wrong I am doing?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you placed the `OutputCache` directive in your `Default.aspx` page? From what I see you're post-backing to `Default.aspx` from the page that has the `OutputCaching` directive....

> [PostBackUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.postbackurl.aspx):
>
> The URL of the Web page to post to from the current page when the
>   Button control is clicked. The default value is an empty string (""),
>   which causes the page to post back to itself.

**EDIT:**

I tried the same scenario and I got the same result. No matter how many times I clicked the 3rd button, the page was still cached. I looked in Firebug and I can see this info after the 1st click:

```
Response Headersview
Cache-Control   public, max-age=10
```

Then after successive clicks max-age decreases. Only when max-age reaches 0, the page is requested again from the server. This is the expected behavior.

The thing is: the 3rd button is passing a different param (ABCD) and the page continues to be cached when it shouldn't because the `OutputCache` directive specifies a different param (ID):

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="10" VaryByParam="ID" %>
```

So, I also would like to know why this is happening... since the 3rd button pass a different param (ABCD) it should not cache the page (as per my understanding of the MSDN docs). Maybe we're misunderstanding it all.

Comment: Yes Leniel, Everything I wrote is in Default.aspx. Can you try this demo on your side? I understood your point, the purpose of PostBackUrl is to do cross-page posting, but I also tried doing the same, but still no luck. That's why I end up doing everything inside Default.aspx.

Comment: Leniel, I have edited my question. Can you have a look at it?

Comment: Yes Leniel, I agree with your observations. Ultimately I ended up posting my query in msdn forum. I am also looking to contact any Microsoft guy for sorting out this issue. Thanks for taking out time for this issue :).

Comment: Leniel, can you follow this post: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/netfxbcl/thread/924c15e8-9305-48f3-8103-47200e3f5915 . I have got an answer, but it doesn't makes sense to what he's saying (may be I am wrong). Let me know your thoughts. Also I have posted the query here: http://forums.asp.net/p/1805057/4986786.aspx/1?VaryByParam+of+OutputCache+doesnt+seem+to+be+working .

Comment: Thanks Anup. I've read the answers so far and they look misleading... don't make sense at all ( different from the way I had thought about it )...

Comment: Ya, even I was astonished with the answers I got. Let me know in case you come up with some updates. Good day.

Comment: Leniel, can you again follow the post: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/924c15e8-9305-48f3-8103-47200e3f5915

Answer (score 0):

This is how OutputCache works when using VaryByParam = "ID" - it does a separate cache version for each request with different value for key ID. If user does a request, which does not use ID - a new caching version will be created.
Example:

1. home/index/ID=1 -> Version 1
2. home/index/ID=2 -> Version 2
3. home/index/ID=1 -> Version 1 /reusing cache version for ID=1/
4. home/index/     -> Version 3
5. home/index/Name=Peter -> Version 3 /reusing cache version 3/
6. home/index/Name=Peter&ID=2 -> Version 2 /reusing Version 2 because using ID=2/

So, what we can conclude is that if doing **VaryByParam=ID** then a new version will be using for every value that we use with that param. If we do not use that param in the request, a separate cache version will be created and will be reused in the next requests.